# Getting incorrect facebook friend id

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting a wrong Facebook Friend Id: I am getting some long alphanumeric value in id which, among the other things, is also not unique (e.g. it changes on each call).

Actually I want to use this id as a unique identifier to login, but since it changes every time is not so helpful.

So what's wrong here? What else can I do for unique identification? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I am using this code to get friend list:

```
Bundle required = new Bundle();
                required.putString("fields", "uid, name, picture.type(square), gender, email");

                //Request for friendlist from facebook
                Request req = new Request(session, "me/taggable_friends", required, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response)
                    {
                         is2=response.getGraphObject();             
                         JSONObject json = is2.getInnerJSONObject();
                         readResponse(json);
                         String str = json.toString();
                         saveFileOnSD("data", str);
                        // generateNoteOnSD("frinedresponse", str);
                         Log.v(TAG, str);
                    }
                      });
                Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 30th April 2014 facebook make so many changes, so if you create you facebook **APP ID** after this date you can't get **facebook id** of your friend with  **taggable_friend**, so for getting facebook id of your friend you need to use **"me/friends instead of me/taggable_friend",** but you get only those friend list who are using your app.

Comment: Actually i am getting facebook friend id but id is incorrect. i want to get id of all the friend even they don't using my app.

Comment: This feature removed by facebook but if you have any facebook app which you created before than 30 April 2014, then its work, but once you create a "signed apk" its not work, still i am searching for this problem.

Comment: @Raja it wont work. fb is providing app scoped user id. All the different apps will get different userid for the same user. I experienced similar issue in my well functioning app

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using taggable_friends. Taggable_friends are for if you want to tag friends. It is by design that the id changes every single time you call it.

If you want friends you should use /me/friends but it will only return friends that are already using the app.

Depending on what you need all friends for some solutions can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq